# DropDownList not firing its SelectedIndexChanged when loaded with no datasource

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Today I found a weird problem, I was trying to fire a DropDownList SelectedIndexChanged event but it just didn't work at all. After checking with other DropDownLists I have I noticed the only difference is that they are being filled using a datasource while this one is being filled manually in the backend.

Here is what I have:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DDDynAccount" runat="server" 
onselectedindexchanged="DDDynAccount_SelectedIndexChanged" 
AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Then the Backcode when loading it:

```
DDDynAccount.Items.Add(new ListItem("ANY", "%"));
DDDynAccount.Items.Add(new ListItem("SELECT", "%"));
```

The event which is not being fired:

```
public void DDDynAccount_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    string s = ""; // I have a breackpoint here
}
```

If I do that, the event is never fired.
I've tried setting on and off the AutoPostBack. Nothing.
I've tried making a new control from scratch. Nothing.
I've also tried to call to Databind() once I've added its items manually but using no Datasource. Again nothing.

I have another DropDownList in the same page that works. The only difference is that that one is using a datasource. So I tried this:

```
    List<ListItem> ds = new List<ListItem>();
    ds.Add(new ListItem("ANY", "%"));
    ds.Add(new ListItem("SELECT", "%"));
    DDDynAccount.DataSource = ds;
    DDDynAccount.DataBind();
```

And that will work.

My question is simple. **WHY?** Why cannot I fire the event if Im not using a datasource? Or there is any other problem?

---

I'm using .Net4 with C# in a Web Application.

---

**Update**: Ok Im sorry for this but, after checking the code wrotten here I realized a little detail, the Items I was adding manually had the same value, changing it the problem is fixed. I presume the event is not fired because the value hasnt changed, despite the "SelectedIndexChanged" should be fired not when the value is changed, but when the index is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both items have the same value, so as the first item is selected by default when you select the second item, the Value of the drop down list is **not** changed so as far as the code is concerned nothing changed and there's nothing to do.

Having such code instead:

```
DDDynAccount.Items.Add(new ListItem("ANY", "%%"));
DDDynAccount.Items.Add(new ListItem("SELECT", "%"));
```

Will trigger the event just fine.

This is bug with .NET actually - it works only with `value` assuming it's unique, and not with the item index.

As a side note, to avoid adding more and more items each post back, wrap the adding with such statement:

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    DDDynAccount.Items.Add(new ListItem("ANY", "%%"));
    DDDynAccount.Items.Add(new ListItem("SELECT", "%"));
}
```

**Edit**: was curious about you saying it worked fine with binding data source so tried for myself. Well, it fails with data source as well. With the code you posted:

```
List<ListItem> ds = new List<ListItem>();
ds.Add(new ListItem("ANY", "%"));
ds.Add(new ListItem("SELECT", "%"));
DDDynAccount.DataSource = ds;
DDDynAccount.DataBind();
```

Quick view of the HTML source show that the *value* of each option is actually its text - `ANY` and `SELECT` and not the value you tried to assign. To assign the proper value you need such code:

```
List<ListItem> ds = new List<ListItem>();
ds.Add(new ListItem("ANY", "%"));
ds.Add(new ListItem("SELECT", "%"));
DDDynAccount.DataTextField = "Text";
DDDynAccount.DataValueField = "Value";
DDDynAccount.DataSource = ds;
DDDynAccount.DataBind();
```

And you will experience the same problem as with assigning the items one by one as now the value will be the same.

Comment: Thanks mate, yes I realized that just when I sent the question, so bad I didnt before. Anyway, good to know that this is a .Net bug and not me having to read more books to get it :))) And yes, I avoided a !Page.IsPostBack condition calling the function to sum the code.

Comment: Anyway, if instead of adding the items manually I do it with the datasource, they can have the same value and it works. So, this doesnt happen if you use a datasource, only if you dont.

Comment: Hmmmm, which .Net version are you using? Because I promise it works for me, I've test it again and it works. Mine is C#.Net 4.0 on web Application. You are right about the values though. I show you the HTML down there.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I didnt read you properly, yes you are right. I get it now ;)

Answer (score 0):

I test like you told, if index change but value not change the event will not fire

Answer (score 0):

If I use this:

```
List<ListItem> ds = new List<ListItem>();
ds.Add(new ListItem("ANY", "%"));
ds.Add(new ListItem("SELECT", "%"));
DDDynAccount.DataSource = ds;
DDDynAccount.DataBind();
```

This HTML is printed:

```
<select id="MainContent_DDDynAccount" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$MainContent$DDDynAccount\',\'\')', 0)" name="ctl00$MainContent$DDDynAccount">
    <option value="ANY" selected="selected">ANY</option>
    <option value="SELECT">SELECT</option>
</select>
```

And the event is fired, really.